# getting server updates with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax and requesting constant updates from the server, i've read articles on different ways to accomplish just that but i wanted to make sure that i have a grasp on what is exactly going on and what needs to be done and also if my method would work.

my ajax code would be as follows:

```
function updates() {
     var xmlhttp;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                        //do stuff with data
                        //recall function to check for more updates
                        updates();
                    }
                }           

                xmlhttp.open("POST","./includes/updates.php",true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                xmlhttp.send();    



}
```

and then the php code:

```
<?php


require './db_connect.php';
$result = mysqli_query($con, "--CHECK FOR NEW UPDATES--");
$numrows = 0;

while ($numrows == 0) {
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "--CHECK FOR NEW UPDATES--"); 
   $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   //add delay to lessen load?
   usleep(1000);
}

//convert to JSON and return data

echo $data
```

This isn't my actual code just something i came up with really quick to see if this method would work. I am looking for any advise on the matter, thank you

EDIT: I will be using this function to check for new messages and alerts. the database structure will have a table for each user that will be populated with new messages and alerts only, once viewed they will be moved, so the query to the database and table will only return results if there is new data to be displayed

Comment: Since you tagged `jQuery` in your question, is there a reason you didn't use the built-in AJAX functionality in jQuery? IE. [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: First of all, you're not passing any data to the server, so "POST" should be "GET" - if only for the purpose of semantics and knowing the difference. 
Second, you should check out jQuery ajax, since it makes this sort of thing much easier - 
as far as your php script goes, You don't want to put a database query inside of a loop -- at least not in anything that'll be production -- if you are more specific about what updates you're looking for, we can help you make that better - Also, since you're a beginner, you should definitely check out jQuery ajax. Makes it much simpler.

Comment: seeing as how im new to ajax I am currently learning the roots but will most likely end up using jquery in my final product. sorry for the confusion

Comment: I think you are trying to do long polling. You should set a timeout on  your ajax request so that it's not going continuously.

Comment: @rm-vanda sorry missed that in my quick write up, it will be passing the users id number so the php code knows what table to query. would there be an advantage either way using GET or POST with such little data being passed? Also the response could produce a decent (~20 rows varying in length) amount of data, would the method matter for the response from the server?

Comment: @Pjack What would be a responsible amount of time to let the query run?

Comment: 30 seconds is usually ok. I notice facebook does approx 40 seconds on their long polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to poll for results from the client side, rather than having the web server constantly polling the database (in a loop) on the server side.

An example of a basic polling utilising jQuery `$.get` and `setInterval` is as follows:

```
// Begin polling server every 8 seconds
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    $.get('/server/results', function(data) {
        // Oh look some valid data! Stop the polling
        clearInterval(timerId);
        // TODO: Handle the results however you like
    });
}, 8000);
```

Now your server needs to simply query the database, and output the result set.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, is this an example of frequent polling? is so what is the advantage of this over long pulling? Just to lesson the load on the server?

Comment: Yes, the general rule with making a transaction with the back-end is make that transaction as short as you possibly can, so that the server is free to handle other requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Call the `poll` function on page load. Then it will send an ajax request. If your server responds within 30 seconds it will process the success function otherwise if not it will timeout and start the `poll` again and it will just continue to run. I prefer this method, similar to Facebook. This gives the appearance of real time update. If you inspect element you can see the long polling. It cuts down on the number of requests to the server too.

```
function poll(){
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            url: "/./includes/updates.php"
            }).then(function(response, textStatus) {
                 if(response){
                  //tell the user they have a new message

                  //start the poll again
                  poll();
                 }
            }).always(function(response, errorThrown){
                if(errorThrown == "timeout"){
                    //timedout start the poll again
                    poll();
                }
        });
}
```

I would also set a timeout on the server side too.

In php something like

```
<?php
$now = time();
$timeout = 30;

while((time() - $now) < $timeout) {
    //check for new messages with sql query
    if($messages){
     //echo whatever
    break;
   }
   usleep(1000);
}
?>
```